# AjaxControlToolkit 7.0123 breaks VS2012 Web Application Project

Tags: ajaxcontroltoolkit, asp.net-4.5

I have an existing VS2012 web application that has been running fine until I added in the latest AjaxControlToolkit (7.0123). Initially, I found that the installation broke the behaviour of the UpdatePanel - whereas before I could refresh a page after an asynchronous post-back without repeating the operation I found that after installation the refresh would repeat the previous operation (I guess the post-back was no longer asynchronous).

I then noticed that, at some time in the past, I had commented out a number of the default JavaScript files that are added to a new ASP.NET Web Forms Application so I tried adding them back in. This resulted in an exception:

> 'MsAjaxBundle' is not a valid script name.  The name must end in
>   '.js'.

I then tried replacing the default `<asp:ScriptManager .../>` with `<ajaxControlToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager .../>` this resulted in a new exception

> Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web' or one of its
>   dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

For sanity, I then created a fresh ASP.NET Web Forms Application (VS2012, Update 2) and ran it. No errors. Using "nuget", I then added the AjaxControlToolkit v7.0123 (the latest release). Ran the application again and I get the original exception again:

> 'MsAjaxBundle' is not a valid script name.  The name must end in
>   '.js'.

Once again, I replaced  `<asp:ScriptManager .../>` with `<ajaxControlToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager .../>` and once again this results in

> Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web' or one of its
>   dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Can anybody shed any light on what else I need to do to resolve this? I can find no documentation to say anything needs to be changed manually when adding the toolkit.

Thanks,

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Answer found at http://stephenwalther.com/archive/2012/09/20/september-2012-release-of-the-ajax-control-toolkit.aspx (always just after posting the question huh)

- Replacing `<asp:ScriptManager .../>` with `<ajaxControlToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager .../>` is correct
- Need to remove reference to MsAjaxBundle
- Need to remove Assembly="System.Web" from script references

This fixes the exceptions (both in the new project and the original).

It does not however resolve the problem with the UpdatePanel no longer posting back asynchronously. I will raise this as a new question.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the April 2013 Release of the Ajax Control Toolkit see Stephen Walther's latest blog post:

http://stephenwalther.com/archive/2013/04/30/april-2013-release-of-the-ajax-control-toolkit.aspx

I was missing the new web.config settings that allow the AjaxFileUpload control to work in the new release

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" maxRequestLength="42949672" />
    <httpHandlers>
      <add verb="*" path="AjaxFileUploadHandler.axd" type="AjaxControlToolkit.AjaxFileUploadHandler, AjaxControlToolkit"/>
    </httpHandlers>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
    <handlers>
      <add name="AjaxFileUploadHandler" verb="*" path="AjaxFileUploadHandler.axd" type="AjaxControlToolkit.AjaxFileUploadHandler, AjaxControlToolkit"/>
    </handlers>
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="4294967295"/>
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you see this "'MsAjaxBundle' is not a valid script name. The name must end in '.js'."

The Best thing you can do is:

1. Go to the site Master (Double click on it )
2. Search for "MsAjaxBundle" or "  "
3. Comment this line eg. <%----%>
4. Save or compile your program and then run it

Thank God is working by now