# Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web' or one of its dependencies.

Tags: ajax, visual-studio-2012, webforms, nuget, system.web

I'm getting the following error:
Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

To reproduce it, Create a new website in Visual Studio 2012. It creates a new templated website.
Add the AjaxControlToolkit via NuGet.  Change the scriptmanager to the toolkit scriptmanager on the masterpage.
Clean solution, compile solution, run in debug.

I checked and double checked my references to System.Web (version 4.0 is what shows). All perfect. Running Code Analysis - no errors, no warnings, all perfect.

Any ideas? (All I want to do is create a simple website using a few AJAX controls)

Answer (score 1):

Solution:
Remove reference to MsAjaxBundle
Remove Assembly="System.Web" from all script references

Add 2 new script references 
asp:ScriptReference tag  Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Name="ExtenderBase.BaseScripts.js" 
asp:ScriptReference Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Name="Common.Common.js"

voila! 
I found the answer here:
[AjaxControlToolkit 7.0123 breaks VS2012 Web Application Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15851857/ajaxcontroltoolkit-7-0123-breaks-vs2012-web-application-project)